# Plotting a Throw Trajectory in R

Tags: r

Here's the data

```
structure(list(ThrowSpeed = 73.01448, PopTime = 1.600322, ExchangeTime = 0.69207, 
TimeToBase = 0.908252, CatchPositionX = -1.37782, CatchPositionY = 2.65907, 
CatchPositionZ = 0.5019, ThrowPositionX = -4.6391, ThrowPositionY = 4.21092, 
ThrowPositionZ = 3.75256, BasePositionX = 62.55366, BasePositionY = 3.48949, 
BasePositionZ = 62.22463, ThrowTrajectoryXc0 = -4.58109, 
ThrowTrajectoryXc1 = 81.31084, ThrowTrajectoryXc2 = -8.11795, 
ThrowTrajectoryYc0 = 4.26976, ThrowTrajectoryYc1 = 13.99541, 
ThrowTrajectoryYc2 = -16.32979, ThrowTrajectoryZc0 = 3.7578, 
ThrowTrajectoryZc1 = 67.17178, ThrowTrajectoryZc2 = -3.07957), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Essentially I want to make a graph where the catcher (CatchPosition) and Base (BasePosition) are visible with a visualization in R of the throw (ThrowTrajectory)

I understand this is rather open ended, so if you have any ideas or suggestions onto how to create an effective visual for this in R, it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

These variable names are not self explanatory, but here goes a shot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(CatchPositionX, CatchPositionY, color = "Catch")) +
  geom_point(aes(BasePositionX, BasePositionY, color = "Base")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = ThrowTrajectoryXc1, xend = ThrowTrajectoryXc2,
                   y = ThrowTrajectoryYc1, yend = ThrowTrajectoryYc2),
               color = "black", arrow = arrow())
```

[image]

Comment: yeah sorry, the ThrowTrajectoryXc1 is like the first order polynomial for the x coordinate with the integer being the order polynomial and variable being the coordinate